The action 'RESET' with payload {"index":0,"routes":[{"name":"BottomNavigation"}]} was not handled by any navigator
I'm trying to create an app using React Native and right now I'm getting the problem referenced in the title whenever I try to sign in.
This in the screen SignIn.js:
navigation.reset({
 index: 0,
 routes: [{ name: 'BottomNavigation' }],
});

I imagine that the error occurs because the screen is ommited in App.js when the user is logged out (signedIn only turns true once the user has signed in):
return (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
      {signedIn ? (
        <Stack.Group screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="BottomNavigation"
            component={BottomNavigation}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Chat"
            component={Chat}
          />
        </Stack.Group>
      ) : (
        <Stack.Group screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="SignIn"
            component={SignIn}
        <Theme>
          <SubmitButton onPress={() => submit()}>Submit</SubmitButton>
        </Theme>
      )}
    >
      {(fields) => <>{Object.values(fields)}</>}
    </SchemaForm>
  </ScreenContainer>
);


There is no need to navigate, conditional routes will load automatically.
